# Mocha tests passing on localhost but not when running on TravisCI

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, travis-ci

I've written a test suite like so:

```
this.slow(1000)
this.timeout(6000)
var response, client
before(function(done) {
    client = new UsergridClient()
    client.GET(_collection, function(err, r) {
        response = r
        done()
    })
})

it('should not fail when a callback function is not passed', function() {
    // note: this test will NOT fail gracefully inside the Mocha event chain
    client.GET(_collection)
})

it('should return a 200 ok', function() {
    // ******** LOGGING ********* //
    console.log(response)
    // ******** LOGGING ********* //
    response.statusCode.should.equal(200)
})

it('response.entities should be an array', function() {
    response.entities.should.be.an.Array
})

it('response.first should exist and have a valid uuid', function() {
    response.first.should.be.an.Object.with.property('uuid').with.a.lengthOf(36)
})

it('response.entity should exist and have a valid uuid', function() {
    response.entity.should.be.an.Object.with.property('uuid').with.a.lengthOf(36)
})

it('response.last should exist and have a valid uuid', function() {
    response.last.should.be.an.Object.with.property('uuid').with.a.lengthOf(36)
})
```

When running this test locally, all tests pass. When running on TravisCI though, the `response` variables are being reported as `undefined` even inside the tests. This suggests to me that there's some sort of asynchronous mixup, but using the `done()` callback on the `before()` should mitigate that, shouldn't it? I even tried adding `done` callbacks to every subsequent test, but that still isn't working.

The notable error here is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'property' of undefined
```

and it looks like that's being thrown from:

```
response.first.should.be.an.Object.with.property('uuid').with.a.lengthOf(36)
```

which makes me think Travis' environment doesn't like `Object.with` or maybe even just `.with`?

Here's my .travis.yml file:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- '5.1.0'
install: 
- 'npm install'
- 'npm -g install mocha'
script: 
- 'mocha tests'
```

And here's the run log:

```
Using worker: worker-linux-docker-7421b08d.prod.travis-ci.org:travis-linux-8
system_info
Build system information
Build language: node_js
Build group: stable
Build dist: precise
Build image provisioning date and time
Thu Feb  5 15:09:33 UTC 2015
Operating System Details
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
Linux Version
3.13.0-29-generic
Cookbooks Version
a68419e https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/tree/a68419e
GCC version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
clang version 3.4 (tags/RELEASE_34/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Pre-installed Ruby versions
ruby-1.9.3-p551
Pre-installed Node.js versions
v0.10.36
Pre-installed Go versions
1.4.1
Redis version
redis-server 2.8.19
riak version
2.0.2
MongoDB version
MongoDB 2.4.12
CouchDB version
couchdb 1.6.1
Neo4j version
1.9.4
RabbitMQ Version
3.4.3
ElasticSearch version
1.4.0
Installed Sphinx versions
2.0.10
2.1.9
2.2.6
Default Sphinx version
2.2.6
Installed Firefox version
firefox 31.0esr
PhantomJS version
1.9.8
ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 3 2011
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T17:29:23+00:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_76, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-29-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
git.checkout
0.36s$ git clone... cloning
remote: Counting objects: 315, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (153/153), done.
remote: Total 315 (delta 74), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 161
Receiving objects: 100% (315/315), 48.32 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (156/156), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
$ cd path/to/proj
$ git checkout -qf <hash>
This job is running on container-based infrastructure, which does not allow use of 'sudo', setuid and setguid executables.
If you require sudo, add 'sudo: required' to your .travis.yml
See http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/ for details.
3.13s$ nvm install 5.1.0
######################################################################## 100.0%
Checksums empty
Now using node v5.1.0
$ node --version
v5.1.0
$ npm --version
3.3.12
$ nvm --version
0.23.3
install.1
17.95s$ npm install
npm WARN engine underscore.inflection@1.3.0: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0 <0.12"} (current: {"node":"5.1.0","npm":"3.3.12"})
npm WARN deprecated lodash@0.9.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@2.4.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0.
app@2.0.0 /home/travis/build/path/to/app
   ... list of packages
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON app@2.0.0 No repository field.
install.2
1.71s$ npm -g install mocha
/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v5.1.0/bin/mocha -> /home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v5.1.0/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha
/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v5.1.0/bin/_mocha -> /home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v5.1.0/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha
/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v5.1.0/lib
   ... list of packages
1.50s$ mocha tests

    init() / initSharedInstance()
  ✓ should be an instance of Client
  Client
    initialization
  ✓ should fail to initialize without an orgId and appId
  ✓ should initialize using properties defined in config.json
  ✓ should initialize when passing orgId and appId as arguments, taking precedence over config
  ✓ should initialize when passing an object containing orgId and appId, taking precedence over config
    GET()
IncomingMessage {
  _readableState: 
   ... omitted
  readable: false,
  domain: null,
  headers: 
   ... omitted
  client: 
   ... omitted
  req: 
   ... omitted
  request: 
   ... omitted
  toJSON: [Function: responseToJSON],
  caseless: 
   Caseless {
     dict: 
      { 'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        date: 'Sun, 29 Nov 2015 22:44:54 GMT',
        server: 'Apache-Coyote/1.1',
        'set-cookie': [Object],
        'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
        connection: 'Close' } },
  read: [Function],
  body: 
   { action: 'get',
     application: '19748000-24b6-11e3-9877-6d1a3f81ba2f',
     params: {},
     path: '/tests',
     uri: 'https://api.mydomain.com/myorg/sandbox/tests',
     entities: 
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ],
     timestamp: 1448837094623,
     duration: 65,
     organization: 'myorg',
     applicationName: 'sandbox',
     cursor: 'LTU2ODc0MzQzOkdCcGJDbVpTRWVXVndibnE5RUdORGc',
     count: 7 },
  entities: 
   [  ],
  first: 
   { uuid: 'b3037a1a-4cd6-11e5-8aa2-0b8eb3ce43ee',
     type: 'test',
     name: '01',
     created: 1440692071473,
     modified: 1440692071473,
     food: 'pizza',
     metadata: { path: '/tests/b3037a1a-4cd6-11e5-8aa2-0b8eb3ce43ee' },
     value: 1 },
  entity: 
   { uuid: 'b3037a1a-4cd6-11e5-8aa2-0b8eb3ce43ee',
     type: 'test',
     name: '01',
     created: 1440692071473,
     modified: 1440692071473,
     food: 'pizza',
     metadata: { path: '/tests/b3037a1a-4cd6-11e5-8aa2-0b8eb3ce43ee' },
     value: 1 },
  last: 
   { uuid: '181a5b0a-6652-11e5-95c1-b9eaf4418d0e',
     type: 'test',
     created: 1443493848240,
     modified: 1443493848240,
     metadata: { path: '/tests/181a5b0a-6652-11e5-95c1-b9eaf4418d0e' },
     title: 'Charlotte\'s Web' } }
  ✓ should not fail when a callback function is not passed
  ✓ should return a 200 ok
  ✓ response.entities should be an array
  1) response.first should exist and have a valid uuid
  2) response.entity should exist and have a valid uuid
  3) response.last should exist and have a valid uuid
    POST()
  ✓ should not fail when a callback function is not passed
  ✓ should return a 200 ok
  4) response.entities should be an array
  5) response.entity should exist and have a valid uuid
  ✓ response.entity.author should equal "Sir Arthur Conan Doyle"
    PUT()
  ✓ should not fail when a callback function is not passed
  ✓ should return a 200 ok
  6) response.entities should be an array
  7) response.entity should exist and its uuid should the uuid from the previous POST requets
  ✓ response.entity.narrator should equal "Peter Doyle"
    DELETE()
  ✓ should not fail when a callback function is not passed
  ✓ should return a 200 ok
  ✓ response.error.name should equal "service_resource_not_found"
    authenticateApp()
  ✓ should return a 200 ok
  ✓ should have a valid token
  ✓ client.appAuth.token should be set to the token returned from 
  ✓ client.appAuth.expiry should be set to a future date
    appAuth / setAppAuth()
  ✓ should initialize by passing a list of arguments
  ✓ should initialize by passing an object
  ✓ should initialize by passing an instance of AppAuth
  ✓ should initialize by setting to an instance of AppAuth
  Query
    _type
  ✓ query._type should equal "cats" when passing "type" as a parameter to Query
  ✓ query._type should equal "cats" when calling .type() builder method
  ✓ query._type should equal "cats" when calling .collection() builder method
    _limit
  ✓ query._limit should equal 10
    _ql
  ✓ should support complex builder syntax (chained constructor methods)
  ✓ not operator should precede conditional statement
  ✓ string values should be contained in single quotes
  ✓ boolean values should not be contained in single quotes
  ✓ float values should not be contained in single quotes
  ✓ integer values should not be contained in single quotes
  ✓ uuid values should not be contained in single quotes
  36 passing (696ms)
  7 failing
  1) Client GET() response.first should exist and have a valid uuid:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'property' of undefined
      at Context.<anonymous> (tests/lib/client.test.js:69:48)
  2) Client GET() response.entity should exist and have a valid uuid:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'property' of undefined
      at Context.<anonymous> (tests/lib/client.test.js:73:49)
  3) Client GET() response.last should exist and have a valid uuid:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'property' of undefined
      at Context.<anonymous> (tests/lib/client.test.js:77:47)
  4) Client POST() response.entities should be an array:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined
      at Context.<anonymous> (tests/lib/client.test.js:108:50)
  5) Client POST() response.entity should exist and have a valid uuid:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'property' of undefined
      at Context.<anonymous> (tests/lib/client.test.js:112:49)
  6) Client PUT() response.entities should be an array:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined
      at Context.<anonymous> (tests/lib/client.test.js:146:50)
  7) Client PUT() response.entity should exist and its uuid should the uuid from the previous POST requets:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'property' of undefined
      at Context.<anonymous> (tests/lib/client.test.js:150:49)
The command "mocha tests" exited with 7.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Comment: Have you tried `before_install: npm install -g mocha` instead of `install` in your .travis.yml? I say that because I use mocha myself and it works totally fine, and this is the only difference I spot.

Comment: No, Mocha is running fine - I can see the other tests passing.

Comment: Not seeing the actual errors in the log. There's the "mocha tests" line, but nothing after it.

Comment: Sorry @palfrey that was an earlier log dump. Adding it in now.

Comment: Just to check: that list of removed packages that get installed includes "should" right?

Comment: It's in the package.json as a devDependency. And since the other tests are passing, it must be installed.

Comment: The plot thickens: cleaned my npm packages and did a fresh `npm install`, now I can reproduce it locally. Still no idea why `should` isn't handling the properties though? Investigation under way.

Comment: http://unitjs.com/guide/should-js.html indicates that `should.be.an.Object` is a valid shortcut for `instanceof(Object)`. But that's the killer here - it's not extending the former properly.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, I'm not entirely sure how, this syntax was working fine using whatever version of [should.js](/questions/tagged/should.js) I had installed locally. When deploying to TravisCI, it must have installed a newer version which caused any type-checking assertion to fail.

Where this previously worked (according to [this](http://unitjs.com/guide/should-js.html)):

```
response.first.should.be.an.Object.with.property('uuid').with.a.lengthOf(36)
```

It actually needed to be called with parentheses:

```
response.first.should.be.an.Object().with.property('uuid').with.a.lengthOf(36)
                               // ^^
```

... as indicated in the [official docs](https://shouldjs.github.io/#should).